Different format in .mbox and email saved locally with mutt: convert split .mbox file into the same format as mutt?
I am trying to move to mutt for mail client and am trying to have email localy. I have 2 sources of saved email:

the first one was obtained from the .mbox file form google: I wrote a script which extacted each email in a separated .txt file (to be able to 1. search with grep content of file 2. organize them according to years and 3. not having to parse a single 10GB+ file each time I want to access the emails).
the second one was obtained by saving locally the email from with neomutt application.

There are many fields which seem to be coded differently in a significant way. For example:
In the .mbox split saved file as txt, the fist line  is (I think because there are several similar looking field):
From user@mail.com Tue Jul 21 07:48:31 2022

Whereas in the file saved locally by mutt, the first line is as follows
From 1370888888881122222@xxx Tue Jul 21 07:48:31 +0000 2022


The email adress is actually only displayed in other fields below:
...
X-Sender: user@mail.com
...
Return-path: <user@mail.com>
...

Moreover the file saved by mutt appears in color in vim (as if it detects the file structure and not for for the split .txt file of the .mbox)
Here are my questions:

Why those differences
How do vim detects the structure difference
(most importantly!:) is it possible to convert the split .txt file from the mbox in the same format as the one saved in mutt?


@MarcusMüller Thank you for your comment. I wrote that to be able to search with grep content of file and organize them according to years without having to run through the whole .mbox file. This was also before using mutt

@MarcusMüller regarding your second comment: I probably use mutt the wrong way but when I run neomutt -f my10GB_mboxfile.mbox it takes quite a long time (10-20 seconds) to load and then when neomutt was finally done, I was not able to parse through the emails (as nothing was read)

thanks! I see! Can't guarantee things would be faster, opening a lot of files is usually slow; performance would get better for modifications, though.

the highlighting in vim might such hinge on the file extension; have you tried renaming one of your .txt files to .mbox or .eml?

@MarcusMüller thanks again! There is not even a file extension to the mutt-saved files. And even if I change them actively (e.g. with extension .txt), the highlighting (nicely) persists

And regarding the parsing: I am aware that it will not make things faster but let's say: you are looking for an email that you know was sent /received in 2023. Then you can narrow down the search to that year directory only. I have the impression that it makes stuff more tidy and less clunky but maybe I missed something

Moreover regarding the failure to open the .mbox file, I wrote a small dummy example in a SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78281245/mojibake-character-encoding-problem-when-opening-a-converted-html-file-in-neov . I cannot open thins file with neovim -f dummy.mbox. Maybe I should ask a separate question for this?

for fun, I just tested this with a 1.4 GB mbox file, and sure, my neovim takes some time to open it, because it's large (you can use tricks to open in raw, but then you won't get the highlighting)

@MarcusMüller Do you have another workflow when you want to open such a big file?

See also formail (shipped with procmail to process mailbox and mail files). Searching more effectively including by date/sender/subject/body can be done with indexers such as mairix or notmuch both of which you can easily hook into mutt.

many thanks for your comments @StéphaneChazelas. What do you use: mutt? or the the combinations of the one you mentioned? or Both? Do you have a particular workflow to recommend? Do you know where I could find some basic examples to start with?

@ecjb, I've been using mutt for over 25 years. I have some adhoc scripts to hook it with mairix also using zle with history for the mairix search specification, you'll probably find more resources online about using notmuch with mutt. I see Debian and derivatives have a notmuch-mutt package about that, I still have to come round to giving it a try.
